# pytorch custom urdu dataloader (text and images)

Tags: python, pytorch, dataloader

I am new on pytorch lib and trying to load a dataset i acquire online. Its a OCR in Urdu language. the structure of the dataset is
-Train_image:
-name1.jpg
-name2.jpg

-train_labels.csv
-column 1 (Files name)
-name1
-name2
-column 2 (text in the corrosponding file)
-label1 (urdu text)
-label2 (urdu text)

now how can i load this data to train a CNN and A RNN for detection and recognition?

Comment: can u elaborate on dataset, i m not getting it!

Comment: is the question about how to read a .csv file, how to implement your custom dataset class, or how to work CNNs and RNNs ?

Comment: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html

Comment: this is about reading dataset.